# Node.js - pass parameter to endpoint from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, directory, client

I have a textbox and a button on HTML page. I want the client to be able to pass to the server the path to any directory, and then the server respond with the directory content.

I think the problem is in the var folderToBeRead. I tried to pass the textbox.value with document.queryselector, but the terminal says "document is not defined"

//SERVER

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
  });

var folderToBeRead = './folder' //I want this to be the chosen path from client


fs.readdir(folderToBeRead , function (err, files) {
  app.get('/dir',(req,res) => {
    res.json(files);
  });
});

app.listen(5000);
```

//CLIENT

```js
var url_data = 'http://localhost:5000/dir';



function show(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url_data,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        success: function (response) {
            response.forEach(elemento => {
                $("#content").append(`<p>${elemento}</p>`);
            });
            $('#btn1').css({display:'none'});
            $('#btn2').css({display:'block'});
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
};


    function hide(){
        $("#content").html(``);
        $('#btn2').css({display:'none'});
        $('#btn1').css({display:'block'});
    };
```

Comment: first of all, I don't see in your clien-side call any data pssed to the server, and as you sending data to server it should be a POST and not  get.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see in your client-side call any data passed to the server, and as you sending data to server it should be a POST and not a get.

try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url_data,
    type: "POST",
    data: "YOUR_DATA_HERE",
    dataType: "json",
    header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    success: function (response) {
        response.forEach(elemento => {
            $("#content").append(`<p>${elemento}</p>`);
        });
        $('#btn1').css({display:'none'});
        $('#btn2').css({display:'block'});
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Furthermore why are you using  json to pass a single string?